# How to get user's shape from Google Maps JavaScript API V3 and analyze it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On the project I am currently working, I am asking the user to search for a location on a map. When user finds the location, he/she needs to draw a rectangle on the area that he needs information about. How can I get the `shape(rectangle)` that is drawn on the map `as object` for example, so I can use the methods `getNorthEast()`, `getSouthWest()` and get the proper coordinates of the object?

What I have been trying is this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'dragend', function(e) {
            if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE) {
                // Send bounds.
                var rectangleShape = e.overlay;
                rectangleShape.type = e.type;
                // var coordinate = rectangleShape.getNorthEast(); -- Won't allow me to use it.
                // var coordinate = rectangleShape.getBounds().getNorthEast(); -- Won't allow me to use it too.
            }
        });
```

But, as I have written in the code, it won't allow me to use those methods meaning I am doing wrong something. Any ideas/code to share with me to solve this?

**EDIT:**
What's inside the `drawingManager`

```js
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                  google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
                ]
            },
            rectangleOptions: {
                editable:true,
                draggable:true,
                geodesic:true
            }
        });
```

**EDIT 2:** In the `@MrUpsidown` answer I have asked him how to catch events like `bounds_changed` on rectangle after moving the rectangle on map or resizing.

So, here is the answer if anyone needs to implement that:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(event) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(event, 'bounds_changed', function(){
                if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE) {
                    var bounds = event.getBounds(); // Here are the new bounds after moving the rectangle around or resizing it.
                  
                  // Rest of the code here.
                }
            });
```

Check the edited post of `@MrUpsidown` for another approach how to solve this.

Regards,
Dejan

Comment: Is zooming the map not an option?

Comment: Users have the option to zoom and zoom out the map. But that has nothing to do with this I guess, they draw a rectangle on map. I need that rectangle as an object.

Comment: Why are you using a google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE instead of a goole.maps.RECTANGLE?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event

Comment: Cause I am not creating hard-coded rectangle . I am giving the users rectangle overlay so they can draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the bounds of your overlay, then do this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {

    var bounds = event.overlay.getBounds();
});
```

Then you can use `bounds.getNorthEast();` etc.

**Edit:** To reply to your second question: an easy way to listen to more events would be to convert your overlay to a [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle) once you have drawn it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {

    // Get shape bounds
    var bounds = event.overlay.getBounds();

    // Remove overlay from map
    event.overlay.setMap(null);

    // Create a rectangle here with the overlay bounds
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/w3r0bo1e/)</kbd>

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? How can I trigger the `bounds_changed` event now on the shape? Cause I need to update the bounds when the user either moves the shape on the screen to new position or resizes it? I added the event like this:   `google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'bounds_changed', function(event)`, but it won't trigger.

Comment: Never mind, solved it :) Will update my post now if anyone needs to know how to do it.

Comment: Perfect answer again. Thank you very much. I have posted my approach too as it is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();
```

You can get the lat and long with .lat() and .lng() like the following:

```
var contentString = '<b>Rectangle moved.</b><br>' +
  'New north-east corner: ' + ne.lat() + ', ' + ne.lng() + '<br>' +
  'New south-west corner: ' + sw.lat() + ', ' + sw.lng();
```

Comment: `rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();` doesn't work too. I don't have the option to use any of that.
As I have written above, rectangle is not predefined in code. It is drawn by the user.

Comment: Try changing the event to 'overlaycomplete'

Comment: Also, try using e.overlay.bounds.getNorthEast();

Comment: @MrUpsidown already wrote this and I have accepted the answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Google's example for this at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event